# The added UIBarButtonItem doesn't do any action

Tags: uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the UIBarButtonItem display, I can add a button without problem, but the added UIBarButtonItem doesn't do any action. Any one please help?

```
    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action, target: self, action: #selector(sayHello))

    func sayHello() {
    print("Hello")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftBarButton, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Did you assign a target an an action to your `UIBarButtonItem`? Docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: Isn't that what i did in the UIBarButtonItem's declaration? And it didn't work

Comment: Of course; sorry for the silly question.